# Remember last viewed slide on refresh with slick.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, slider, slick.js

I'm using slick.js as a content browser. As such, my slider has a number of images to peruse through. I'd like to be able to refresh the web page and have slick remember the last slide I was viewing. I'm new to jquery and javascript so any guidance would be appreciated.

Here's the code I'm working with:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // Carousel Options
    $('.mycarousel').slick({
        infinite: true,
        accessibility: true, mobileFirst: true,
        adaptiveHeight: true,
        arrows: false, draggable: true,
        useCSS: true, cssEase:'linear', focusOnSelect: true,
        dots: true, appendDots:$(document.innerHTML = "<p>&nbsp;</p>"),
        lazyLoad: 'ondemand',
    });
    $('.leftArrow').on('click', function(){
        $('.mycarousel').slick("slickPrev");
    });
    $('.rightArrow').on('click', function(){
        $('.mycarousel').slick("slickNext");
    });
    $(window).on('resize orientationchange', function() {
        $('.mycarousel').slick('resize');
    });
});
```

Comment: Any chance you could provide the code you are working with? It is very difficult to provide an acceptable answer without knowing what the problem you are solving truly is.

Comment: Look at my answer. If it helped please accept as answer and if you have any difficulties just ask

Comment: Sorry for the late one, the project got interrupted. I've added the code I'm working with.

Answer (score -1):

I myself did some research and this is what I found:

```
$('#yourCarousel').on('slid.bs.carousel', function () {
    var currentSlide = $('#yourCarousel div.active').index();
    sessionStorage.setItem('lastSlide', currentSlide);
});
if(sessionStorage.lastSlide){
    $("#yourCarousel").carousel(sessionStorage.lastSlide*1);
}
```

Instead of sessionStorage you could also use:

```
localStorage.setItem('lastSlide', currentSlide)
```

Comment: `slid.bs.carousel` is not a Slick event and `.carousel()` is not a method that Slick recognizes.